# iPhone: Pushing View Controller causes Slow and Jerky Keyboard Animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a model-view-controller design app with more than 20 views and imageviews.

In one view, I have a textfield that gets set to first responder when the view displays such that the keyboard is immediately visible. When I push this view onto the navigation controller the display of the keyboard is very slow and jerky. However, when  I pop the view, the retraction of the keyboard is fast and smooth.

What could cause the slow and jerky animation when pushing the view? I really have to have the keyboard visible when the view loads.

Comment: Just to clarify, is it the keyboard animation that is the problem or is the animation for the entire view that is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet, where you set your first responder?

Comment: The entire view animation is the problem. the keyboard animation is fast. but the view is animating slowly after keyboard animates.

Comment: u can set the "becomeFirstResponder" in "viewDidAppear" and try again

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you have so many different view controllers allocated e.g [[MyViewController alloc] init...] that your test platform is pre-occupied with managing the memory associated with your application. Basically, in Layman's terms, your iPhone doesn't have enough processing power to perform a smooth animation and handle all the views you have open.

You can do one of two things:

1.) Release your view controller objects when opening a new view controller.

2.) Since you said you have a lot of UIImageViews, instead of allocating an entirely new view controller each time you want to perform a transition reload the class data and then push, present, or pop to your view controller object. eg. [[self navigationController] presentModelViewController:self];